# Mesibo Javascript Popup Integration for one to many chat

Tags: javascript, popup, integration, one-to-many, mesibo

I have integrated Javascript Messenger & Popup https://github.com/mesibo/messenger-javascript/

I want use Popup Integration or Multitab-Popup for more than one user like Javascript Messenger where we can chat with multiple user (one-to-many)

For that I have display list of users on Page and on clicking on user I am loading popup in iframe with destination user mobile no, destination name and logged in user access token from mesibo.
It is working fine for single user while I am loading second user in iframe then first user getting logged out.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Mayby ask Mesibo team. I suppose that it is not possible to have two users logged in one brwoser tab.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize mesibo only once and not every-time you open a new pop-up. The best place for mesibo initialization is when your page loads.

Your popup code should only have send and receive functionalities. If you are using mesibo popup.html example, you should extract initialization and move it to your main page.

Comment: Thank you for answerr.. I am not sure how it works because for each popup I need to pass different destination phone, name while mesibo user access token remain same.

Comment: You are mixing up token and destination. Please read my answer again.

Comment: Hi Mark,Thank you for comment but without initialization of mesibo on main page and not on popup page its not working. if you have some sample code it will be very helpful to me.

Comment: Share your relevant code here, from initialization and popup.

Comment: Sorry for late reply

https://anvisinfotech.com/contract/chat/php/dec_popup_api.php?op=login&phone=919619815079&name=Divyesh&frmid=1
List Page when you click second user first will got logged out
Kindly download code from here...
https://anvisinfotech.com/messenger-dec-zip.rar